# How to find available path bindings for a component in Teleriks Web Report Designer?

Tags: binding, telerik-reporting

I've been creating reports using Teleriks Report Web Designer and I've usually been able to find the paths for bindings through other people's questions and posts. Still, every now and then I'm stuck doing some exploratory guessing/researching to find the correct string to represent a path I need to bind to.

How can I analyze a component or where can I go to to determine all possible bindable paths of that component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vote for this to be implemented:
https://feedback.telerik.com/reporting/1549727-the-binding-in-web-report-designer-does-not-list-the-available-paths

Meanwhile you can get the paths from the [standalone designer](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/report-designer-tools/desktop-designers/standalone-report-designer/overview#starting-the-standalone-report-designer-for-net).
[image: Property paths]